# iOS: Play song from iCloud

Tags: ios, avplayer

I'm currently working on a music app for iOS. I'm using AVPlayer to play the songs.
And this works fine so far, except for song that are not downloaded from iCloud.
This songs are not played :(

```
NSArray *itemsFromQuery = [[MPMediaQuery songsQuery] items];
MPMediaItem *song = [itemsFromQuery objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *songURL = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
AVURLAsset *urlAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:songURL options:nil];
```

Here in this example songUrl is null for an iCould song but it is OK for a song already downloaded...

But there needs to be a way to play iCloud songs, because apps like Groove are doing this...

Thanks for your help,
Urkman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot reading and testing it looks like there is currently no way to play a iCloud song without MPMusicPlayerController.

Apps like Groove also using the MPMusicPlayerController...

Comment: Thaanks for the answer. It gives me more points  to move ahead

Comment: Is it possible to trigger a silent download while playing using MPMusicPlayerController